# Multiclass Confusion Matrix: ValueError: At least one label specified must be in y_true

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I can't figure how can I fix this so I can get a multiclass confusion matrix. I am doing a multiclass classification for brain tumors. Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    
DATADIR = r"/content/drive/MyDrive/Estudos/Mestrado MTFM/TESE/Dados/Dataset2/Subgrupo"
CATEGORIES = ["Glioma","Meningioma","NoTumor","Pituitary"]
for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
        break
    break
    
IMG_SIZE = 150
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)) 
                training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
create_training_data()

X = []
y = []
for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)
print(X.shape)
X = X/255.0  
X = X.reshape(-1,150,150,1)

tumor_classifications = os.listdir(r"/content/drive/MyDrive/Estudos/Mestrado MTFM/TESE/Dados/Dataset2/Subgrupo")

y = to_categorical(y, num_classes = 4)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)

X_train = X_train.reshape(9184,5625)
X_test = X_test.reshape(2296,5625)
y_train = y_train.reshape(9184,1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(2296,1)

classifierDT = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifierDT.fit(X_train, y_train)
ClassificationDT = classifierDT.predict(X_test)
print("Acurácia: %.3f" % (accuracy_score(ClassificationDT, y_test)*100))
```

The classifications are being shown as:

array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)

And then:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, ClassificationDT)
print (cm)
```

But I get a 2x2 matrix, instead of a 4x4. I tried to put the labels but it didn't work out.

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, ClassificationDT, labels=['Glioma', 'Meningioma', 'NoTumor', 'Pituitary'])
```

From which I obtained:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-90ef1d38cff1> in <module>()
----> 1 cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, ClassificationDT, labels=['Glioma', 'Meningioma', 'NoTumor', 'Pituitary'])

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight, normalize)
    319             return np.zeros((n_labels, n_labels), dtype=int)
    320         elif len(np.intersect1d(y_true, labels)) == 0:
--> 321             raise ValueError("At least one label specified must be in y_true")
    322 
    323     if sample_weight is None:

ValueError: At least one label specified must be in y_true
```

Comment: Can you check the unique values in `ClassificationDT` using `numpy.unique(ClassificationDT)`?

Comment: array([0., 1.], dtype=float32)

Comment: Try labels as `labels = [0,1,2,3]`.

Comment: It apparently worked, but it returned a 4x4 matrix like this:
```
[[1610  112    0    0]
 [ 102  472    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0    0]]
``` 
That is equal to the 2x2 I had previouly obtained, plus the columns and rows with zeros.  It should show me the matrix with the 4 categories...

Comment: I really think that the problem is because I intended to have 4 categories, but the output that I have is simply 0. and 1., instead of 0., 1., 2., and 3., and I can't figure out where the problem is, once I wrote `num_classes = 4` at the beggining of the code.

Comment: If the data has multiple classes but the predictions don't, then the model might have to be tuned. The data could be skewed with samples in only 2 classes. These are some reasons I can think of.

Comment: Could you help me with that?